# Samesite y cookies de sesion

Tags: javascript, php

Alguien podria explicarme como funciona el samesite=none secure.

Vi que esto es lo que esta impidiendo que pueda usar una cookie en chrome, la cual puedo usar perfectamente en firefox, alguno con un poco mas de idea en estos temas que me explique si tengo que agregar encabezados en peticiones, o en el mismo server php ? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que [esto](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/01/get-ready-for-new-samesitenone-secure) te puede servir de ayuda.

Comment: @kemilbeltre es eso que vos decis, lo que dice la documentacion explica mi problema, lo que no comprendo es como implementarlo en php, o fetch. Encontre esto, pero nose como aplicarlo https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/php.md

Answer (score 1):

creo que ya encontre la respuesta, la dejo aca para los que tengan mi duda en algun momento.

Sucede que cuando se crea la cookie en el server diferente al del dominio donde esta el front, el front no recibe las cookies que vengan de servidores de terceros, es decir, las bloquea por completo, por lo que si se quiere acceder a una variable global de sesion como en php, por cada consulta se debe hacer lo siguiente:

**1)En el lado del cliente asi debe lucir la peticion para que sea identificada la cookie y nos la devuelva**

Es imprecindible colocar este atributo o bandera en fetch. "include". Esto permite que fetch obtenga y envie credenciales como la sesion del user, cookies,etc.

**Cliente:**

EJ:

```
 fetch('https://www.ejemploapi.com.ar/server.php?session=get',{

credentials: "include"

});
```

**Servidor:**

Ademas de usar el encabezado de peticiones cruzadas que a continuacion los dejo, deberan usar una funcion que setea las cookies y permite devolverlas en las peticiones. Vamos por partes:

**Encabezados requeridos:**

cabe aclarar que pueden ir al comienzo de su server, antes de que se ejecute el resto de su codigo que necesita estos "permisos CORS".

```
   //header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   //header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Eso deberia bastar, pero cuando desde fetch mandamos el atributo
credentials: "include" , estamos obligados por motivos de seguridad a no usar comodines, sino mas bien, el dominio de donde enviamos los datos, en este caso, seria el dominio del servidor donde estemos realizando el fetch o consulta, no el backend.

**EJ:**

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.desdeaquihagofetch.com");
           header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Muy bien, ya tendriamos nuestras cabeceras, no deberian haber peticiones rechazadas por cors, checkea en tu consola si hay alguna, y verifica denuevo los pasos de esta publicacion.

**Esta es la parte que nos interesa en este caso**

La peticion volvera vacia en el caso de consultar una sesion, ya que en el año 2020 chrome y otros navegadores han cambiado su politica de cookies, y las sesiones son cookies, por lo que al consultarlas no podriamos accederlas.

EJ: Si consultamos desde fetch a este metodo get, volvera vacio:

```
//aca pregunto por la peticion

if (isset($_GET['session'])){

//aca pregunto si se creo en algun momento una sesion con $_SESSION['user']

//reanudamos la sesion que hay creada en el server

    session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){

//aca devuelvo lo que tenga SESSION['user']

echo $_SESSION['user'];

}
}
```

Simple, ¿no?, pero lo mas probable es que chrome devuelva vacia tu consulta, por mas que ya halla una sesion creada en el server, ¿porque?. Bueno porque es un server de terceros, y no comparte las cookies, como exprese anteriormente.

**¿Y como hago que devuelva mi sesion?**

**RESPUESTA:**

Desde php, hay una funcion para esto, que debera ejecutarse si mal no entendi, cada vez que se efectue una peticion a la sesion,

Y esa funcion tiene que ir antes del **session_start()**.

Principalmente lo que necesitamos son los atributos httponly = **true** y samesite=none, y para que samesite pueda ser = **none**, necesitamos que haya un tercer parametro, secure = **true**

```
    $secure = true; 
$httponly = true; 
$samesite = 'None';
$maxlifetime = 50000; 

if(PHP_VERSION_ID < 70300) {
    session_set_cookie_params($maxlifetime, '/; samesite='.$samesite, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $secure, $httponly);
} else {
    session_set_cookie_params([
        'lifetime' => $maxlifetime,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'secure' => $secure,
        'httponly' => $httponly,
        'samesite' => $samesite
    ]);
}

session_start();
```

Y listo, ya con esto su sever deberia devolver las sesiones, y chrome deberia recibir las cookies correctamente, otra cosa que puede pasarles es que su configuracion de chrome no permita las cookies o esten bloqueadas, en ese caso tampoco devolvera la cookie el server.

**Hago esta documentacion, porque me costo bastante entender el concepto, es algo nuevo esto del samesite, y creo que a mucha gente puede servirle, saludos!**

Recuerden:
frontend -> {credentials: **"include"**}
backend -> **samesite=none**, **secure=true**, **httponly=true**